# Finding Unicode characters from Object

Tags: javascript

I have a big object containing unicodes, data structure is like below

```
var data = {
   "1f1f7-1f1fa":[["\uD83C\uDDF7\uD83C\uDDFA"],"\uE512","\uDBB9\uDCEC",["ru"],28,3],
   "1f1fa-1f1f8":[["\uD83C\uDDFA\uD83C\uDDF8"],"\uE50C","\uDBB9\uDCE6",["us"],28,4]
   ....
   ....
};
```

And I would like to make it like

```
var final = {
    "\uD83C\uDDF7\uD83C\uDDFA" : "ru",
    "\uE512" : "ru",
    "\uDBB9\uDCEC" : "ru"
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here is the code and [bin](http://jsbin.com/cefowugihufi/1/edit)

```
var final = {};

for(var i in data) {

    var arr = [], spliceI = null;

    arr = data[i];

    arr = arr.filter(function(str){
       return str;
    });

    loop:
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){

       if(arr[j] === +arr[j]){
          spliceI = j;
          break loop;
       }
    }

    arr.splice(spliceI, arr.length);

    var vals = arr.splice(-1).pop();

    if(vals == undefined) debugger;

    console.log(vals);

    arr = arr.concat.apply(arr, data[i]);

    for(var k = 0; k < vals.length; k++){
      for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
          final[arr[j]] = vals[k];
      }
    }
}
```

But unexpectedly data[i] is turning into [], so I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` for `vals` operation.

How can I fix this, this is for emojis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the jsbin, I noticed that the first entry of data is: `"00a9": [["\u00A9"], "\uE24E","\uDBBA\uDF29", ["copyright"], 0, 0]`. Let's call this entry "copyright".

The statement

```
arr = arr.filter(function(str){
   return str;
});
```

will turn this "copyright" entry of `data` into the value:`[["\u00A9"], "\uE24E","\uDBBA\uDF29", ["copyright"]]` because the 0 values return false, causing them to be filtered out. I think the intention of this function is to remove undefined elements, this is the assumption I am using in this answer. This in turn will cause `spliceI` to remain null at the end of your loop labeled "loop:", as the loop is looking for numbers, and the filtered array no longer has any numbers in it.

Removing the first entry from `data` removed the error, confirming this.

Updating your filter code to the following:

```
arr = arr.filter(function (str) {
    return typeof(str) !== 'undefined';
});
```

Then fixed the error even when the first entry of data was present. Here is a [bin](http://jsbin.com/cefowugihufi/9/edit?js,console) with the updated code, running on a smaller dataset.